# When saving a SwiftUI view as an image, the content is reduced and there is an unnecessary background that appears

Tags: ios, swiftui, uigraphicsimagerenderer

My view doesn't have a black background when displayed, but after saving it as an image, the content of the view is reduced, and a black background appears above it.

View display on iPhone
[image: my view]

Export View to Image
[image: view to image]

Here's the whole code.

```
import Foundation
import Photos
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
struct MyImageView: View {
    @State private var image: UIImage?
    @State var viewWidth = 0.0
    @State var viewHeight = 0.0
    @ObservedObject var imageSaver = ImageSaver()

    var imageUrl = "https://pic.netbian.com/uploads/allimg/160709/215802-1468072682c2c8.jpg"
    
    func calculateSize() {
        let maxWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let maxHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 100
        if maxHeight/maxWidth >= image!.size.height/image!.size.width {
            viewWidth = maxWidth
            viewHeight = maxWidth * image!.size.height/image!.size.width
        } else {
            viewHeight = maxHeight
            viewWidth = maxHeight/(image!.size.height/image!.size.width)
        }
    }

    private func loadImage() {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: imageUrl)!) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("Error loading image: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                return
            }

            if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = uiImage
                    calculateSize()
                }
            } else {
                print("Failed to create image from data")
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    var myView: some View {
        ZStack {
            if self.image != nil {
                Image(uiImage: self.image!)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
            }
            Text("hello girl").font(.title).foregroundColor(.red)
        }.frame(width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
            .background(Color.black)
            .onAppear {
                loadImage()
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            myView
            Button("save image") {
                myView.snapshot { image in
                    if let image = image {
                        imageSaver.saveSnapshot(compressedImage: image)
                    } else {
                        print("Failed to capture snapshot image.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func snapshot(completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        view?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .black
        view?.layoutIfNeeded()
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            let image: UIImage = renderer.image { _ in
                controller.view.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            }
            controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
            completion(image)
        }
    }
}

class ImageSaver: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPresented = false
    @Published var title: String = ""
    @Published var message: String = ""

    func saveSnapshot(compressedImage: UIImage) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .addOnly) { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(
                    compressedImage, self, #selector(self.saveError), nil
                )
            case .denied:
                self.title = NSLocalizedString("access_denied", comment: "")
                self.message =
                    NSLocalizedString("snapshot_saver_1", comment: "")
                self.isPresented = true
                print("access denied")
            case .limited:
                self.title = NSLocalizedString("snapshot_saver_2", comment: "")
                self.message =
                    NSLocalizedString("snapshot_saver_1", comment: "")
                self.isPresented = true
                print("limited access only")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("access not determined")
            case .restricted:
                print("access restricted")
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func saveError(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        isPresented = true
        if error != nil {
            title = "failed"
            message = "save image failed"

        } else {
            title = "success"
            message = "save image success"
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    MyImageView()
}
```

To ensure a perfect consistency between the displayed view and the exported image, I have fixed the width and height of the view.

Comment: Since iOS 16 you can use `ImageRender`. Do you need to support older versions?

Comment: Looks like your calculated frame is not taking the safe area insets into account correctly. Is that what the `-100` is there for? Suggest using a `GeometryReader` instead, which gives you both the screen dimensions and the insets. `UIScreen.main.bounds` is deprecated anyway.

Comment: I need support iOS14+, myView add .ignoresSafeArea() works. Thanks you all.